# Simplifying an equation with negative exponents

Tags: excel, algebra

It has been 15 years since I needed to do any complicated algebraic equation simplification. Specifically, I need to simplify this equation so that it will properly calculate in an Excel spreadsheet. I'm doing nonlinear optimization models so sometimes x=0 resulting in an error. I know to flip the numerator & denominator to get rid of the negative. However, I'm still getting a Div/0 error. If someone could just give me the properly simplified version, I will be able to back into what you did to understand how to apply it in the future.

(35 + 100x^-(1/3))*x

EDIT, I forgot one piece of the formula, everything inside the () is * x too. Update it.

Comment: 0 can not be raised to a negative power, since it is analogous to division by 0. So when X is 0, excel can not calculate your equation.

Comment: Test if any part evaluates to zero or any cell is zero and then deal with it for example =if(b1=0, this_calc,that_calc) etc

Comment: I updated the formula forgot that everything inside the () was * x too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you cannot avoid the laws of simple maths.  This formula:

```
=35+B1^(-1/3)
```

is equivalent to:

```
=35+1/B1^(1/3)
```

if you set **B1** to zero we get the equivalent to:

```
=35 + 1/0
```

which will raise the error.

**EDIT#1:**

```
(35 + 100x^-(1/3))*x
```

is the same as:

```
35*x + 100 * x^(-1/3) * x^1
```

is the same as:

```
35*x + 100 * x^(2/3)
```

and if we set x=0 we get

```
35*0 + 100*0
```

which is:

```
0
```

Comment: I forgot one piece of the formula, everything inside the () is * x too. Updated it. Does that change your answer?

Comment: @BenWildmon  see my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you. I knew I had to "multiply through" but I just didn't understand how to apply it. This helped.